# calculating and finding difference in pairs of values in c

Tags: c

I really need help with this question.

> Write a program that accepts six(6)
>   pairs of values from the user and then
>   calculates and stores the difference
>   of each pair of values in an array.The
>   array of calculated values should then
>   be sorted into ascending order and
>   printed on the screen.

I got through with inputting the six pairs of values, what I'm getting trouble with is the difference and storing in ascending order.

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[12], num1, num2, i;
    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("Enter first number for pair ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        printf("Enter  second number for pair ");
        scanf("%d", &num2);

    }
    if (num1 > num2)

        printf("arr[i-1=num1-num2 ");
    else

        printf("arr[i-1]=num2-num1 ");
    {

        for (i = 1; 1 < 7; i++)
            printf("%7d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: C++ or C#? Your title conflicts with the tag... Also, what have you tried so far (code-wise)?

Comment: "Write a program that..." So where's your program?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're happy to help people with their homework, but we're not a magic factory to get you good marks in school :) We're here to help people become better programmers. Pplease note our FAQ suggests ["the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Please also read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more details on what we, as a community, like to see in questions. :) Thanks.

Comment: thanks for including the source :) if the question isn't re-opened eventually, feel free to post a new question with the source code included from the start :) -- and hopefully with better indentation, too; note the `{}` button on the editor toolbar (I know, I usually ignore those things too, but this time it's useful :) -- select all your code after pasting it in, and then hit the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the difference immedialy after you read both values and store the value.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
        int arr[7], num1, num2, i;
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            printf("Enter first number for pair ");
            scanf("%d", &num1);

            printf("Enter  second number for pair ");
            scanf("%d", &num2);

            //check differences now
            if(num1>num2)
            {
                    arr[i]=num1-num2;
                    }
            else
            {
                    arr[i]=num2-num1;
                    }
        }
    }
```

For the ordering of the vector, you could use a bubble-sort algorythm.
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Bubble_sort.c

The reason for changing the vector and for limits is because vector positions go from 0 to n and not 1 to n, meaning that the for should go from 0 to 6 ( < 7  or  <= 6 ).